# what is the differences between [NgClass] and [class] in Angular JS2?

Tags: angular, binding

if we have a view element that has these three attributes

```
class="red" [class]="isGreen?green:cyan" [ngClass]="'blue'"
```

does the angular merge the output of these attribute or make one of them override the others

and if we have

```
[class]="getElementClass()"
```

how many times angular will call that method and when

suppose at first that method will return "red" after 1 min it will return "green"

the class set of that element at after the first call will be for example

> blue cyan magenta **red**

after the second call
it will be:

> blue cyan magenat  **green**

How AngularJS does that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does the angular merge the output

yes it does (see also [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ecbParGytwaRF39Eq4b3?p=preview))

```
some dummy code to satisfy SO
```

> [class]="getElementClass()"

every time change detection is run

> How AngularJS does that?

Every time change detection is run, the bindings are re-evaluated

Comment: I reproduced the claim that all three class forms do merge. ✓ The plunker example above doesn't currently show the `[class]` result getting merged, but if you change it from `[class]="isGreen?green:cyan"` to e.g. `[class]="isGreen?'green':'cyan'"` you can see the merge.